# lsp-mode, Jump to Next Warning

Tags: lsp-mode

In a *C#* `lsp-mode` buffer, when something is highlighted, is there a "jump to next warning or error" function?

I don't see anything like `lsp-next*` or `lsp-jump*`.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

`lsp-mode` integrates with `flycheck` or `flymake`. Please check the variable `lsp-diagnostics-provider`.

For example, `flycheck` provides `flycheck-next-error` and `flycheck-previous-error` to help navigate across errors/warnings. You can also use `flycheck-list-errors` to see the errors list. Similarly, `flymake` provides `flymake-goto-next-error` and `flymake-goto-prev-error`.

Answer (score 1):

For real-time diagnostics, `lsp-mode` utilizes either [flycheck](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/) or a built-in package [flymake](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Flymake.html) (in *Emacs* open manual with <kbd>C-h R</kbd> `flymake` <kbd>RET</kbd>).

**`flycheck`** documentation on [interaction with errors](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/error-interaction.html#navigate-errors) states:

> By default Flycheck hooks into Emacs’ standard error navigation on M-g
> n (next-error) and M-g p (previous-error).

This is what, supposedly, you're looking for, since `flycheck` is a recommended package for use by `lsp-mode` and is [configured by default](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/tutorials/CPP-guide/#diagnostics).

**`flymake`** documentation in its turn also describes how to navigate between errors. To reach this section in *Emacs* use <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(flymake) Finding diagnostics")` <kbd>RET</kbd>. Now the section states the following:

> ‘flymake-goto-next-error’ and ‘flymake-goto-prev-error’ are let you
> navigate to the next/previous erroneous regions, respectively.  It
> might be a good idea to map them to ‘M-n’ and ‘M-p’ in ‘flymake-mode’,
> by adding to your init file:
>
> ```
>  (define-key flymake-mode-map (kbd "M-n") 'flymake-goto-next-error)
>  (define-key flymake-mode-map (kbd "M-p") 'flymake-goto-prev-error)
> ```

And, since we've touched the subject of diagnostics, you may find a list of [related `lsp-mode` custom options](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/settings/diagnostics/) useful. Especially note **`lsp-diagnostics-provider`** custom option on that list, which can be used for selecting -- as its name broadly hints -- one of the mentioned providers of the diagnostics.